# Prove that cardinal of $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{N}$ without Cantor diagonal argument

Tags: cardinals, alternative-proof

All proofs I know that the cardinal of $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{N}$ involves the Cantor diagonal argument.

Is there any proof which not involves that? Can anyone find out an alternative proof (better elemental than using very high-level theories)?

Comment: See [Cantor's first set theory article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article) and [Cantor's first uncountability proof](https://academickids.com/encyclopedia/index.php/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491925/cantors-first-proof-that-bbbr-is-uncountable).

Comment: What "high-level" theory are you trying to avoid? As far as I can tell, the Cantor diagonalization argument uses nothing more than a little bit of basic low level set theory conceps such as bijections, and some mathematical induction, and some basic logic such as argument by contradiction. Granted, it uses all those things in a highly imaginative manner, but nonetheless I don't see where the "high-level" part of the argument resides.

Comment: @LeeMosher Surely Model theory could prove that but I seek the same elemental level as Cantor does, or a little bit higher

Comment: See my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/401608/113405)

Comment: The diagonal argument is so basic that is very hard to imagine a simpler proof. The method only appears complicated (which it is not at all) because it is a thought process ! In reality we cannot produce this list , not even ignoring that it has infinite many elements ; most numbers cannot even be written down or described. Nevertheless, the argument is perfectly valid.

Comment: If one finite set includes all elements of another set, yet it contains one extra element (not included in the other set), then the cardinals are different. An infinite set is a union of an infinite number of finite subsets. If you can add  to any finite subset of $\mathbb N$ an extra element that is not a natural number but is a real number, then you’ve obtained a finite subset of $\mathbb R$ with a different cardinal. You don’t even need to add a real number: just extend any finite subset of naturals with the next natural number.

Comment: @WindSoul That a finite list cannot contain every real number is immediately obvious , less obvious is whether an infinite list can do this. This is what the question is about. So, I do not understand the point of bringing finite sets into play.

Comment: The point is that an infinite set is a union of an infinite number of finite sets. We can’t count the cardinal of $\mathbb N$ but we can extend any finite subset of $\mathbb N$ to construct a finite subset of $\mathbb R$ with a larger cardinal. Thus we can construct the entire set of naturals as a union of subsets, each subset having a cardinal less that the corresponding subset of reals and we still haven’t constructed the entire real set.

Comment: @WindSoul I am not following. But it sounds like such an argument would also apply to the set of algebraic numbers which is however countable !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

Suppose $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$.  Then there is a sequence $r_1, r_2, \ldots$ containing all real numbers in $[0,1]$.  The collection of open intervals $(r_n - 2^{-n-1}, r_n + 2^{-n-1})$ cover all of $[0,1]$.  Since $[0,1]$ is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), some finite subcollection of these intervals cover $[0,1]$ as well.
The total length of that subcollection is less than the total length of the original collection: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$.  But that's impossible: an interval of length $1$ can't be covered by a finite set of intervals of total length less than $1$.

Comment: With the risk of being wrong: for a union of open intervals to cover a closed interval, then open intervals must be overlapping and overflow the closed boundaries. Finding a finite set of such intervals still requires overlapping and overflow. The original closed interval is a subset of the union.

Comment: @WindSoul - the original collection covers the entire interval because every real number in $[0,1]$ is by assumption one of the $r_n$, and therefore contained in its interval. Because $[0,1]$ is compact, some finite set of those intervals must cover $[0,1]$ themselves. That is what "compact" means, and you find proofs that $[0,1]$ is compact in many places. It is the very fact that finding such a finite collection is impossible that provides the contradiction to $\Bbb R$ being countable.

Comment: I apologize for keeping on correcting myself. Just learning.
The limit of sum of all lengths of open intervals is 1 but the sum itself is less than 1. To cover the compact interval you’re missing an infinite set of values that result from gaps between two consecutive open intervals arranged such as the union of two consecutive intervals is an open interval missing the border element between the two intervals.

Comment: @WindSoul The sum of the lengths of all the open intervals is $1$, and each length is positive, so the sum of the lengths of any finite subcollection is less than $1$.  Of course I could have chosen smaller intervals so the infinite sum was also less than $1$.

Comment: The length of each open interval is less than $\frac{1}{2^n}$ because the length never reaches its limit. You think- I believe, that using the entire set of intervals, each centred in $\{r_n\}$ you must have covered the compact since $\{r_n\}$ covered it. I think that the entire set $\{r_n\}$ builds up to a set of lengths that adds to less than 1 and for this reason you can’t further use the infinite union to define the compact.

Comment: The problem is about cardinality. The cardinality of any set is less than the cardinality of its inclusive superset. My intuition tells me that cardinality on naturals is less than of rationals, reals, complex. The only question is what happens between rationals and irrationals (excluding rationals). We could argue the coverage of [0,1] but that’s irrelevant since no real compact has the same cardinality with the entire real set, for the fundamental reason that the entire real set contains at least one extra element. Misunderstanding these fundamentals led to my answer being forcibly removed.

Comment: @WindSoul You are wrong.  The cardinality of $[0,1]$ is the same as that of the reals. It's easy to find a $1-1$ correspondence between the interval $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok. If every element in (0,1) corresponds to itself in (0,1) then which element in (0,1) corresponds to 1 in (0,1]?

Comment: Who says each element must correspond to itself?  If you want to map $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb R$, take $x$ to $\text{arctanh}(2x-1)$.

Comment: I just gave you an example where one set is extended with only one extra element into another set with different cardinality. I also told you already that your open intervals never add up to length 1. You don’t need to trust me or anyone else, just do the addition yourself. You may think that you can always get another number but you forget that the corresponding interval only adds to a sum that never reaches its limit. Keep adding them intervals, it doesn’t matter: you’ll never reach 1.

Comment: I will be stopping now because we are on irreconcilable terms. I enjoyed both your answer as well as the debate. Hope to meet you again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142807/discussion-between-robert-israel-and-windsoul).